# Uncaught TypeError: d.getFullYear is not a function at Y

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am getting an error "**Uncaught TypeError: d.getFullYear is not a function at Y**" when I am trying to pass data from CSV file to a variable declared in script written in Javascript for D3 charts. My variable wants data in below format.

```
var dataset = [{
  "name": "ABAC",
  "date": [
    ["2016-01-11", 0, "2016-02-15"],
  ] 
}];
```

Data stored in CSV file is as given below:

```
name,date
AAA,"2016-01-11,0,2016-01-11"
BBB,"2016-01-11,0,2016-01-11"
```

My code is

```
var dataset = []
d3.csv("data1.csv", function(data) {
dataset = data.map(function(d) { return [ "name", "date" ]; })
```

Comment: seems like you have 2 csv columns BBB, and "2016-01-11,0,2016-01-11".  The quotes make that one value and "2016-01-11,0,2016-01-11" is not a valid date.  Maybe it should be "2016-01-11", "0", "2016-01-11"?

Comment: return ["name", "date"] seems weird. Should that be return [d[0], d[1]]?

Comment: @chris - You're right, my CSV has 2 columns. But in the second column I need to assign an array of values  i.e ["2016-01-11", 0, "2016-02-15"] to the variable called date. You can see the sample declaration pasted above. Thanks!

Comment: @CamJohnson26 - I am getting the same error message if i use [d[0], d[1]] in my code.

Comment: if that is supposed to be an array of dates then maybe 0 is being parsed as a Number and Number has no getFullYear method.  Maybe make the 0 a string if you are expecting it to be parsed as a date.